# Adding <p></p> in loop exercise

Tags: javascript, loops

Hi I got stuck in looping exercise hope someone can help me.

> Display each iteration of looping away in a <  p   > </ p> tag 
> Looping away 
> Looping away 
> Looping away 
> Looping away 
> Looping away

This is my code

```
var count = 0;<br>
while (count <10) {<br>
  document.getElementById('loopDisplay').textContent += 'looping away';<br>
  count++;<br>
  }
```

The following code displays looping

"awaylooping awaylooping awaylooping awaylooping awaylooping awaylooping awaylooping awaylooping awaylooping away".

I tried to put <  p> tags in quotation marks etc., but it does nothing unfortunately. I know it's a very basic stuff but I'm a newbie to JS. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah instead of using `textContent` use `innerHTML` which allows for html elements (p tags) to be parsed and show correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Using document.getElementById('loopDisplay').innerHTML allows you to write html tags with your text as you see ive done in my example here. Also, each iteration of your while loop replaces the *entire* text within the p tags, so for each iteration you need to tell it to include all the text already between the p tags from the previous iterations and then add any other text, including the br tag.
Also you had html br tags randomly placed in the javascript code which i removed.

```js
var count = 0;
while (count <10) {
    const loopDisplay = document.getElementById('loopDisplay');
    loopDisplay.innerHTML = loopDisplay.innerHTML+'looping away<br>';
  count++;
 }
```

```html
<p id="loopDisplay"></p>
```

Comment: For an even better answer, don't just add "try this" but explain what you changed and why

Comment: Thanks Hans, noted and updated